# How do I do stuff to a class instance before #initialize is called?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a class where an instance variable *has* to be set up during initialization, or the class won't work. The class is designed to be heavily subclassed, and I don't want all subclasses to have to call `super` in their `initialize` overloads, so I would like to set the instance variable *before* the initialization function is called.

Is is possible, by overloading `Class#new` or something similar, to do some custom instance initialization *before* the `initialize` function is called?

Like:

```
class Foo < MySuperClass
  def initialize
    # @foo is already set to 123 because of the magic in MySuperClass
    assert @foo == 123
  end
end
```

Comment: can you give an example, explaining the need for this behavior?

Comment: @xlembouras I thought I had done that in the question. The top level superclass defines a set of methods that all assume a certain instance variable has been initiated in the `#initialize` method. If a user overrides `#initialize` then all these methods break. I did this myself and had to debug for a while before I realized that the instance variable was `nil`. "The point of this behavior" is to be able to do some initialization *before* the subclass does, with the added bonus that the subclass can't accidentally prevent the superclass from initializing, triggering confusing errors.

Comment: @xlembouras Here is the specific case I'm talking about: https://github.com/Hubro/Datastruct. Several methods assume that `@data` is a defined hash and will fail if it's not initialized.

Comment: I'm sure there is a clever way of doing this -- BUT -- in Ruby it is normal to call `super` when overriding a class.  If your child classes do this when overriding initialize(), then you don't have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interesting way in [this forum thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/74160#109994):

```
class MySuperClass
  def self.new(*args, &block)
    instance = allocate()

    # Pre-initialize
    instance.instance_variable_set(:@foo, 123)

    instance.send(:initialize, *args, &block)

    return instance
  end
end
```

This overrides the default `Class.new` method and creates instances manually. This means I can jump in and set instance variables before I call `initialize`.

Comment: Hubro, I modified my answer above to include a "cleaner" way.

Comment: After removing `**kwargs` (which is inconsistent and arguably buggy) and reading up on `allocate`, I am convinced this is the cleanest way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the template method pattern instead of relying on `#initialize` in the child class, like this:

```
class Parent
  def initialize
    @foo = 123
    my_initialize
  end

  # Concrete classes must override
  def my_initialize
    raise NoMethodError
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def my_initialize
    puts @foo
  end
end
```

Another way, if you prefer not to use a template method, is to `prepend` a module that contains the initialization logic (`prepend` was added in Ruby 2):

```
class Parent  
  def self.inherited(class_name)
    class_name.prepend Initializer
  end

  module Initializer
    def initialize
      # Your initialization code
      @foo = 123

      # Call your child class's initialize
      super
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def initialize
    puts @foo
  end
end
```

Here is a good primer on Module#prepend: http://gshutler.com/2013/04/ruby-2-module-prepend/

Comment: Are there any advantages to using the prepend-trick over using the method in my answer? Personally I think using `Class#new` and `Class#allocate` *looks* cleaner and simpler.

Comment: There is no technical problem to do this with Ruby. I personally don't like messing with built in methods. It is really a hack more than anything, and `Module#prepend` was added to the core language in part to alleviate the need for such hacks.

Answer (score -1):

What about lazy initialization

```
class MySuperClass
  protected
  def foo
    @foo ||= 123
  end
end

class Foo < MySuperClass
  def initialize
    assert foo == 123
  end
end
```